# Websocket Java EE7 - Number of connection

Tags: java, websocket

I made a very basic chat application using @ ServerEndpoint.

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/{room}", encoders = ChatMessageEncoder.class, decoders = ChatMessageDecoder.class)

But I need to know how to control the number of connections that this room (Received by parameter) can receive?

is possible to have this management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    if(session.getOpenSessions().size() > maxConnections) {
        session.close(new CloseReason(...));
    }
    // ...
}
```